# Python Generate a lexicographic ordered output from array of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I'm working on a Python(3) program in which I have to write a function to generate an output which will be a list of strings in lexicographically order.

Here's an example:
if we pass a string like: `??2??00` which i called a `pattern` then it has to replace the question mark with an integer for example `1` and a keyword called `scheule` denotes the number of `?` and generate an output like below:

```
0020100
0021000
0120000
1020000
```

and, here's what I have tried:
so, if `pattern= '??2??00'` and `scheule=4` then:

```
for ind, p in enumerate(pattern):
    if p == '?':
       s = pattern[ind].replace('?', str(scheule))
       available_schedule.append(s)
       break
     else:
       continue
```

which is not generating the required output, but here's what it generates:

```
['1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, if you enumerate a `str` you obtain a list of characters (strings of length 1). Thus the output.

`str.replace()` will do nothing if the pattern is not found in the string, and will replace all occurrences of the pattern otherwise.

This fragment produces the desired output:

```
pattern = '??2??00'
pattern_pos = [i for i, c in enumerate(pattern) if c == '?']
schedule = '1'
result = pattern.replace('?', '0')
for i in reversed(pattern_pos):
    print(''.join([result[:i], schedule, result[i+1:]]))
```

Output:

```
0020100
0021000
0120000
1020000
```

Comment: Hi @Apalala, it's not generating the desired output.

Comment: Hi @Apalala , can you take a look at this related question,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54732494/7644562  please!